# What is the seventh plane of symmetry in benzene?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers

We get the first six planes of symmetry by joining the opposite edges and vertices. But what is the seventh plane of symmetry?

Comment: Benzene is flat... (hint)

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at this picture which shows some of the symmetry axes and planes. You should be able to see other similar ones. Taken from www.molecule-viewer.com.(You can also use this site to practice working out point groups.)

[image: benzene pic]

Comment: Complementary to the answer by @porphyrin, you may train yourself on the manifold ressources about symmetry at Otterbein university.  All you need is a device capable to handle javascript (which is not java) http://symmetry.otterbein.edu/